# how expand x-axis in bar plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I have a bar plot with xlim([1 5]) as time. Each time contains 5 different grouped data. They are very compacted and plot understanding is not clear. I am going to expand each xlim unit to every 5 grouped data be more readable in each time. How is it possible?

Also, How can i make more distance between each 5 grouped data in each time? I applied bar(data,10,'hist'); but my 5 grouped data are still compacted in each time.

Comment: can you post an image, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Image is: http://i44.tinypic.com/w16w6x.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `bar(X,Y,width)`, with values of `width` lower than the default, which is 0.8. However, that only makes the bars narrower, not closer to the each other within its group.

To make the bar groups farther apart, you could insert `NaN` values between them. For example:

```
bar(1:.5:3,[ rand(1,7); repmat(NaN,1,7); rand(1,7); repmat(NaN,1,7); rand(1,7)] ,.8)
set(gca,'xtick',1:3) % remove unwanted ticks
```

See figure:

[image]